# Muffled snare/clap in dark house & techno

Tags: sound-design, drum

I really like the clap/snare on every second beat that sounds a bit muffled away but still pops out very strong to define the rhythm.

Is that a clap, snare, rim or something else? Any tips how to create this. General advice is appreciated, but more specific on how to do it in Ableton would be great!

Some examples:

(25s in)

Comment: Sounds like a rim-shot sample pitched down to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you'd need to eq away most of the snare, save for the transient, add a little reverb, and compress.

Answer (score 1):

That’s not a snare, it’s a rimshot and/or a woodblock hit.

Comment: this is probably better as a comment on the answer you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

What you are hearing is a pretty dry rim or short snare eqed and bit of reverb. Judging from the track ( the first Josh Butler one Link (dub) ) it sounds like 727 toms etc so safe to assume its a 707.
The key is you are hearing the Lowpass filter resonate on the snare (that spike on the first filter) then it's saturated then eqed more then add a lil reverb... The reason it sounds 'lo fi' is it's mostly mids, it sticks out because he doesn't have a bunch of other things covering up that 1K area where its sitting in the mix.
Basically nailed it in about 20 min just messing around :)

[image]